# Any sample for Fabric8 Continuous Delivery for PHP?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, fabric8

Is there a way to use Fabric8 for PHP project?
All the sample I can find is for java and nodejs.
I am using Fabric8 on Google Container Engine with Kubernetes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not at the moment but we can look to add one in for the next release. There's Java, nodejs, golang, swift and ruby already but we can add php and .net hopefully in the next few days.

Comment: Thanks James. I'll wait for the sample then.

Comment: Hi Ivan - I forgot to mention that we added a real simple [PHP](https://github.com/fabric8-quickstarts/php-example) and .Net examples along with corresponding Pipelines in a recent release.  Until we have a upgrade command you should be able to just delete the fabric8 related replication controllers with `kubectl delete all -l provider=fabric8` and re run `gofabric8 deploy`

Comment: Thanks James will try it today

Comment: Hi @JamesRawlings - can you give more info on the php example please. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Magick - I'm afraid I'm not involved in the fabric8 project anymore and TBH I'm not sure of the state of the community project.  It's now the upstream project for openshift.io but I'm not sure if it's maintained as an onpremis installation anymore.  Incidentally I'm now work on https://jenkins-x.io/ and I should be able to add a php quickstart this week if that helps or interests you / others?